# Parse custom key to value string into actual array

Tags: php, string, parsing

I want to ask if there is some way I can manipulate an already built php function to convert a string in the format `key => value` into actual string with respectively the key and the value? I know that there is parse_str but I believe this is for a `key=value` syntax

The question seems to be unclear so here's an example:

I have a string like `color => blue\nshape => sphere\nsize => medium` and I want to turn that into an array

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I am asking if I can use an included function or I have to build my own

Comment: [extract()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)? But I'm not exactly clear from the question what you want

Comment: can you give an example of the input and desired output?

Comment: @redreggae I have a string like `color => blue\nshape => sphere\nsize => medium` and I want to turn that into an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the chars and use parse_str:

```
$string = 'color => blue\nshape => sphere\nsize => medium';
$string = str_replace(array(' => ', "\\n"), array('=', '&'), $string);
parse_str($string, $output);

print_r($output);
```

EDIT:

Or use a combination of [strtok](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) and [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$string = 'color => blue\nshape => sphere\nsize => medium';
$output = array();
$tok = strtok($string, "\\n");
while ($tok !== false) {
    $array = explode(' => ', $tok);
    $output[$array[0]] = $array[1];
    $tok = strtok("\\n");
}

print_r($output);
```

I realized that strtok is only useful if the delimiter is made of 1 char. So better go with only explode version.

Comment: That's a good idea, but unfortunately some valeus may contain `&`, I can't really do that. Or maybe I could firstly replace `&`s with some unique combination that is not likely to occur, attempt this and reverse the `&`s afterwards. If there's no better suggestion I'd go with that!

Comment: else use my new version or the answer from yones safari.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$str='color => blue\nshape => sphere\nsize => medium;';
$first_arr=explode('\\', $str);
$array=array();
foreach ($first_arr as $value) {
    $var=explode('=>', $value);
    $array[$var[0]]=$var[1];
}
var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'color => blue\nshape => sphere\nsize => medium';
$foo = array();

// Explode your string
$stringParts = explode("\n", $string);

foreach ($stringParts as $item) {

    // For each "item" in your string
    // Separate key from value
    $item = explode(' => ', $item);

    // Assign it as a key-value combination in your new array $foo
    $foo[$item[0]] = $item[1];
}

print_r($foo);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
parse_str(str_replace("\n", "&", $str), $output);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.